# ¿Qué significa este error ?Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Este método calcula si los números dados en un arreglo son primos o no, pero a veces me sale el error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero`, el cual por lo que leí es un error de dividir un número entre cero, pero la verdad intente de todo y no puedo hacer que ese error desaparezca. Alguien que me pueda dar una mano con esto por favor.

```
public int CalPrimo (int arreglo[]) {

    int c=0;
    for (int j=0;j<arreglo.length;j++) {
        c = arreglo[j] - 1;
        while ((arreglo[j] % c) != 0) {
            c--;

        }
        if (c == 1) {
            System.out.println("Es primo:" + arreglo[j]);
        }
    }
    return c;
```

Comment: ¿Por qué tienes un for y luego un while, cuál es tu lógica para resolver el problema?

Comment: En mi programa, antes de calcular cuales son los números primos, primero tengo un arreglo de varios números, y de esos tiene que calcular cuales son y cuales no son primos.

Comment: Comprendo. Lo más probable, según veo en el código, es que haya una posición de `arreglo[]` que traiga el número 1. ¿es eso posible?. Si lo es, debieras añadir código para evaluar el 1 por separado, pues se sabe que el 1 es primo, y por otro lado `c = 1 - 1 = 0` daría lugar a la división por 0 que estás viendo.

Comment: Si, ya lo pude resolver, era un problema en mi main, en uno de mis cases, muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 1):

El problema es especificado en el mensaje, estas realizando una operación de [división por 0](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisi%C3%B3n_por_cero) que trae como resultado una `indeterminación` o `indefinición`.

> java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero

Este problema ocurre aquí,

```
  c = arreglo[j] - 1;
  while ((arreglo[j] % c) != 0) {
```

si el elemento en tu arreglo tiene valor de 1 entonces el valor de `c` será 0, por lo tanto al realizar esta operación se provocaría el error:

```
arreglo[j] % c
```

---

Para obtener los [**números primos**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_primo) puedes hacer uso del método:

```
  boolean esPrimo(int n) {
    for(int i=2;i<n;i++) {
        if(n%i==0)
            return false;
     }
    return true;
  }
```

y llamar el método en tu método `CalPrimo()` para que revise cada elemento del arreglo:

```
  public static void CalPrimo (int arreglo[]) {

    for (int j=1;j<arreglo.length;j++) {    
        if(esPrimo(arreglo[j]))
            System.out.println("Es primo:" + arreglo[j]);                   
        else
            System.out.println("NO es primo:" + arreglo[j]);          
    }   

  }
```

De esta forma como ejemplo de uso puedes imprimir que numeros son primos en un arreglo de enteros:

```
 int arreglo[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30};
 CalPrimo(arreglo);
```

tendrías como salida:

```
Es primo:2
Es primo:3
NO es primo:4
Es primo:5
NO es primo:6
Es primo:7
NO es primo:8
NO es primo:9
NO es primo:10
Es primo:11
NO es primo:12
Es primo:13
NO es primo:14
NO es primo:15
NO es primo:16
Es primo:17
NO es primo:18
Es primo:19
NO es primo:20
NO es primo:21
NO es primo:22
Es primo:23
NO es primo:24
NO es primo:25
NO es primo:26
NO es primo:27
NO es primo:28
Es primo:29
NO es primo:30
```